# can't find one of my hard drives on newly installed linux mint

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, hard-disk

I just installed linux mint alongside windows and I can't seem to find one of the 3 hard drives. Two of them (sda and sdc) are available under `/media/<username>/<drivename>` , but the third one is not there. I can access it when booting to windows. and I can see it when I run this command on linux:

```
$ lsblk -dio KNAME,TYPE,SIZE,MODEL
KNAME TYPE   SIZE MODEL
sda   disk   1.8T WDC WD2003FYYS-7
sdb   disk 931.5G WDC WD10EZEX-08W
sdc   disk 149.1G WDC WD1600JD-00G
sr0   rom   1024M DRW-2014L1T
```

it is the second one in the list.

How do I find it in the file system?
Thanks!

UPDATE: When running lsblk alone thats what I get:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   549M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   1.1T  0 part /media/tarek/ECE04D5DE04D2F60
├─sda3   8:3    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   699G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931.4G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 149.1G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0   149G  0 part /media/tarek/Photography
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Answer (score 0):

If you type just

```
lsblk
```

without any options it will tell you if your disk is partitioned, formatted, mounted

you can use gparted to format it.... gparted will also list what file systems are supported (you may need to install ntfs)

Comment: I did run the command and this is what I got for that drive: `sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 931.4G  0 part`. the other hard drives show the path to them but this one didn't have any path. what does that mean?  forgive me, I'm naive in this area

Comment: see update in post for the full outcome of running the command